# homebrew error - The requested URL returned error: 400

Tags: github, homebrew

I am getting an error 400 when attempting to `reinstall --HEAD` with homebrew.

```
/Users/medialab
≈:≈ brew reinstall --HEAD nmaahcmm
==> Reinstalling nmaahc/nmaahcmm/nmaahcmm 
==> Cloning git://github.com//NMAAHC/NMAAHCmm.git
Cloning into '/Users/medialab/Library/Caches/Homebrew/nmaahcmm--git'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com//NMAAHC/NMAAHCmm.git/':The requested URL returned error: 400
Error: Failed to download resource "nmaahcmm"
Failure while executing: git clone --depth 1 --branch master git://github.com//NMAAHC/NMAAHCmm.git /Users/medialab/Library/Caches/Homebrew/nmaahcmm--git
```

Comment: Thanks! @equal_12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to have been solved with this commit.
https://github.com/NMAAHC/homebrew-NMAAHCmm/commit/5c659da

Just try again.